# analytical geometry

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

We have an affine coordinate system and $3$ points given: $A=(1,0,0)$, $B=(0,1,0)$, $C=(0,0,1)$, $D=(1,1,1)$. I have to find a linear transformation, which depicts the points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ accordingly into $B$, $C$, $A$ and $D$.

Comment: So you have to find a linear transformation that maps $A$ to $B$, $B$ to $C$, $C$ to $A$ and $D$ to $D$? If that is the case, what you are looking for is a permutation matrix.

Comment: yes, i have to find a linear transformation that maps A to B, B to C, C to A and D to D, but what is this permutation matrix ?

Comment: A permutation matrix swaps coordinates. For example, say 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]
\end{align}
Then $\mathbf{P}\left[\begin{array}{c} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} a_2 \\ a_1 \\ a_3 \end{array}\right]$. Note that we were able to swap the first and the second coordinates. Now, which permutation matrix will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Besides observing that you need a permutation matrix, another option is to write your matrix $\mathbf{A} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{array}\right]$ explicitly, and use the given data.

Using the fact that you should map your point $A$ to point $B$, you get

$\mathbf{A}\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$

or equivalently,

$a_{11} = 0$, $a_{21} = 1$, $a_{31} = 0$.

Now use the rest of the data to find the other entries.